# Splash Screen (pantalla de presentación)

Tags: android, splash

He notado que cuando la app se inicia al momento de cargar el splash muestra la `activity` en blanco y después carga, es un segundo, pero quisiera asignar el color, he visto la forma en este foro pero no logro encontrar la pregunta. Espero me haya expresado de forma clara.

El Style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#004D40"
    tools:context="com.example.ash.carritosbeta1.splash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Carros A Padales" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hola Ash esto ya se ha preguntado ahora te señalo la respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias,seria de gran ayuda !

Comment: Esta la respuesta de Webserveis pero también revisa la otra.

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias !

Comment: Un placer saludos!

Comment: Tal vez sea un problema de ciclos de la activity y no tiene nada que ver con el diseño

Comment: Si tiene que ver con el XML ya que hay que aginar el blackground para la pre carga del Splash, en el enlace más arriba lo confirma

Answer (score 0):

Define un activity para tu splash screen y en manifest le indicas que esa activity sera la que se ejecutura primero cuando se inicie la aplicación:

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Cuando le defines los estilos a tu splash screen, entonces en el metodo `onCreate` creas un tipo de timer donde a los 3 segundos de haber iniciado el `SplashActivity`, esta se finalizara e iniciara la actividad principal de la aplicacion:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);

       // esto permite que en un determinado tiempo, se ejecuta el metodo run()
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 3000); // duracion de 3 segundos, despues de ahi se finaliza el splash screen dando inicio la actividad principal
    }
}
```

Comment: Si tengo todo esto, el problema es que cuando inicia la primera ves, carga el fondo blaco y despues el splash, me entiendes?